# Conditionally add WHERE clause in Python for cx_Oracle

Tags: python, flask, cx-oracle

I have the following Python code :

```
    params = {}
    query = 'SELECT * FROM LOGS '
    if(date_from and date_to):
        query += ' WHERE LOG_DATE BETWEEN TO_DATE(:date_start, "MM-DD-YYYY") AND LOG_DATE <= TO_DATE(:date_end, "MM-DD-YYYY")'
        params['date_start'] = date_from
        params['date_end'] = date_to
    if(structure):
        query += ' AND STRUCTURE=:structure_val'
        params['structure_val'] = structure
    if(status):
        query += ' AND STATUS =:status'
        params['status'] = status

    cursor.execute(query, params)
```

Here I am conditionally adding the `WHERE` clause to the query. But there is an issue when I don't have value for the dates as it will not take the `WHERE` and will add `AND` without `WHERE`. If I add the where clause with the query, if there is no filter, then it will give the wrong query. Is there any better way to do this ? I have been using `Laravel` for sometime and it's query builder has a method `when`, which will help to add conditional where clauses. Anything like this in Python for `cx_Oracle` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
params = {}
query = 'SELECT * FROM LOGS '
query_conditions = []

if(date_from and date_to):
    query_conditions.apend(' WHERE LOG_DATE BETWEEN TO_DATE(:date_start, "MM-DD-YYYY") AND LOG_DATE <= TO_DATE(:date_end, "MM-DD-YYYY")')
    params['date_start'] = date_from
    params['date_end'] = date_to
if(structure):
    query_conditions.append('STRUCTURE=:structure_val')
    params['structure_val'] = structure
if(status):
     query_conditions.append('STATUS =:status')
    params['status'] = status
if query_conditions:
    query += " AND ".join(query_conditions)

cursor.execute(query, params)
```

add them in `list` and join values with `AND`

Comment: If the first condition does not have value and second condition has value, then the `WHERE` will not be added.

Comment: Yeah, I just wanted to give you logic, I think rest of the things you can handle :)